# pass canvas content from client to admin using web socket

Tags: javascript, canvas, websocket

The application aim to transfer drawings from client canvas to the admin canvas using web sockets the most smoothly possible. At every mousemove event, the client canvas is compressed to png and sent to server through websocket to finally arrive in the admin window where the image is drawn into the admin canvas.

Actually, the code lag a little in the admin window. It seems the bottleneck is `ctx.drawImage()` but I am not sure.

I wonder if there is a way to first find the bottleneck and then a way to optimise the transfer with debounce or web workers or other.

**Client side:**

```
<canvas id="clientCanvas" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" width="1563" height="528">

function onMouseMove(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('clientCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    socket.emit('SS_onMouseMove', {imageData: imageData});
};
```

**admin side:**

```
<canvas id="adminCanvas" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" width="1563" height="528">

var canvas = document.getElementById("adminCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};

socket.on("SS_onMouseMove", function(response) { onClientMouseMove(response); });

function onClientMouseMove(response) {
    image.src = response.imageData;
}
```

Comment: You should not be sending the entire image over sockets for every mouse event, that could be hundreds a second.  Send the image once then simply send the mouse events after that.  That will reduce your lag 1000%

Comment: @QBM5 on the client side the image can be modified at every mousemove event for instance the client can  drag a shape or draw with a pen tool.

Comment: How would you do it ? I want the admin to see the canvas changes live smoothly as possible

Comment: As i said, as the client produced mouse move events, grabs those events and pass them to the admin.  Then use the same code on the admin as you do on the client to render what the mouse event has done to the image

Comment: @QBM5 Your suggestion make a lot of sense. You can add it as an answer or else I will delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the entire image multiple times a second which is both a heavy load on the client generating the image and the connection which is passing around 2 mb (image as dataUrl) 30 to 40 times a second.

The solution would be to:

- When the connection is made send the original image once
- When mouse events occur on the client, send only those mouse events to the admin and use the same functionality used on the client to render the changes from the mouse event on the admin.

This will decrease the load on the connection dramatically and will require less processing on the client since it wont have to generate a png -> dataUrl multiple times a second